# How to enable mDNS support in android browser address bar

Tags: android, google-chrome

How to get mDNS names (test.local) resolve to ip address in Android Chrome browser  at address bar ?

In windows after installing Bonjour service it works in Chrome browser. Is there similar service which can be activated in Android.

mDNS resolution is possible in Android app like (zeroConfig). I read it is possible to write an app using NSD service. But this support does not seem to be present in Chrome browser of Android.

I am developing an Iot (Internet of Things) web application and mDNS service will make my work and others like me much easier.

Answer (score 10):

Check out the answers here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49188/how-to-get-mdns-working-for-chrome-on-android

natevw's answer:

> I don't think so.
>
> The system DNS resolver in Apple's platforms has in-built support for
>   mDNS, so that pretty much any app eventually winds up using the core
>   getaddrinfo function and supporting mDNS in URLs and hostnames and
>   whatnot.
>
> On Android and other platforms, even if there is a Multicast DNS
>   daemon running and libraries available for using it, "typical" DNS
>   lookups do not. So while recent Android releases do give developers
>   some mDNS features as part of the platform, most do not go out of
>   their way (as they would need to do) to use them.
>
> It's a bummer, but AFAIK there's nothing short of rolling your own
>   custom Android build (or convincing Google to change it) that could
>   really solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Now mdns support avilable in android 12 or higher

Answer (score 1):

Starting from November 2021, Android resolver supports mDNS `.local` resolution.

Source: https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/modular-system/dns-resolver#mdns-local-resolution